# Authorize a user to access Secure Azure Test Site

Tags: azure, testing, azure-active-directory, cypress

I'm setting up UI test tool (cypress.io) to test our new webapp UI, but the test environments are secured using Microsoft's Azure AD to allow access to the test site.

The issue is I need to authorize a test user via cypress to have access via AD to be able to direct to the test site.

I've got a test user with access to the test site, but I'm unsure how I go about doing this with the Azure APIS. I'm brand new to Azure.

My though process would be something like this -

- In Cypress use the BeforeAll to call an api to authorize my user
- Set the localstorage/cookie with the credentials
- navigate to test site
- Start UI test

How to I go about authorizing my test user to access the AD controlled test site.

Answer (score 0):

Applications registered in Azure Active Directory (AAD) are available to all users by default. Access to this application is likely restricted to specific users.

Here his how you can assign a user to an application in AAD (assuming you have the required privileges):

- Log on to the azure portal (portal.azure.com)
- Click on "Azure Active Directory"
- Click on "Enterprise Applications", search for your application
- Click on "Users and Groups"
- Click on "Add User", search for your user
- Select an (application) role
- Click on "assign"

Another possibility is that some type of conditional access is in place, such as type of device, location, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't really answer my question, probably poor explanation in my post. 

I have a test site, that when you visit, you need to be auth'd against the AD to even view it.

Comment: Corporate policies vary. It does sound like conditional access (ex. Corporate managed device, user location, etc...) or whitelisting. Any way you can check with you IT team first?

Comment: Did you had a chance to look into this? I've added this other possibility to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any feedback?

Comment: Hello! Sorry about the late reply, this took a backseat on my work list. The issue is better described here.
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1342